# How to share data with external application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrapping

I have some external application that provide config.json for my Angular 2 application.
I need point of entry for my angular 2 like:

```
angular2Application.setConfig('../config.json'); // in browser console e.g.
```

(then i can use this json in any my service of angular2 app)

and also my app should be able to send some data from service to any external app by the calling some method like:

```
var config = angular2Application.getConfig(); // in external other JS application
```

Probably i should do external calls through global window ? Any help and advices or examples will appreciated.

My angular 2 app service which has global config to be shared.
"Another js app" - this means another js application in the same window.

```js
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {SomeService} from "../../some.service";

@Injectable()
export class SharingService {
  
  public config; // the external app should be able to get this config

  constructor(public someService: SomeService) {
    this.someService.dataChanged.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.config = data;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: you need to define "external application" because the approach won't be the same if t's a server, or another js app in the same window/in a separated one, or maybe some random app running on the same computer...

Comment: Thanks! This is another js app in the same window.

Comment: @n00dl3 I think that he has two or more apps/libs running at the same time and he wants to use the results of one in the other one.

Comment: @Lemmy, that's still obscure, we just know about the angular app, not the other one, how can we access to its properties/methods from  the `window` object, for example...?

Comment: @Lemmy you can share the data holding it on window or you can go with something more complex where both apps get registered and you can notify each app with the results from the other one.

Comment: @camaron Exactly!

Comment: What about using localStorage ?

Comment: @YounesM this json has lot of data strings . Better is indexedDB i guess...

Comment: @Lemmy Firebase?

Comment: @camaron not sure. I've just known that external app - might be native mobile application, running on mobile devices. Imagine, on tablet or mobile in browser running my angular app, and other native mobile appplication can pass some data into angular app and can get some data from last one. Is it possible ????

Comment: @Lemmy Firebase has native android sdk, iOS sdk and js sdk, also there's a package for angular 2.

Comment: @camaron Many thanks!!!! Now i know it. But maybe there are some other methods.

Comment: But if the external app - its another js app in the same window, what i should do for my case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [socket.io](https://socket.io/) and create a socket communication between two applications.

Comment: Thanks. But how big json files i can pass through socket ?

Comment: I don't think there is a limitation of size. I tried to send the source code of the `jquery` on this [demo](https://socket.io/demos/chat/) and no problem occurred :) You can also stringify and parse JSON files as strings to communicate